# How to solve a quadratically constrained linear program (QCLP)?

Tags: optimization, qclp

Can anybody suggest some techniques to solve a quadratically constrained linear program (QCLP)? Any references on standard techniques would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Search for Cutting Plane method which works for convex problems (positive semi-definite matrices $Q$ for a quadratic constraint $x^T Q x \le b$). Otherwise, solving a quadratically constrained linear program becomes NP-hard.